Telegram Бот для отправки видео
Всем привет, делал бота на aiogram, используя библиотеки pytube/pytubefix, мне нужно, чтобы бот отправлял сразу видео по юрл, не скачивая его в репозиторий, а чтобы видео шло напрямую пользователю. Есть вариант достать юрл потока или что-то подобное, или может есть другие пути решения?

также почему-то неделю назад эти библиотеки у меня работали, а сейчас нет, с чем это может быть связано?

Выдает такую ошибку при обычной команде print(yt.streams)                                              Возникло исключение: VideoUnavailable
[91mG3vPU7xblIQ is unavailable[0m
File "C:\Users\максим\Desktop\sosi\yt.py", line 7, in 
print(yt.streams)
^^^^^^^^^^
pytubefix.exceptions.VideoUnavailable: [91mG3vPU7xblIQ is unavailable[0m

используй pytube для того, чтобы получить потоковый url и, собственно, aiogram для отправки видео. только у телеграма есть ограничение на размер файлов, которые можно отправлять

а как получить потоковый url? можешь пожалуйста написать команду, в документации я не нашёл

@user27171043 video_url = 'YOUR_VIDEO_URL',yt = YouTube(video_url),stream = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first().
Если ответ помог, пометь его галочкой

да, но эта команда не возвращает url видео, а передает параметры html формата, поэтому если ввести bot.message.answer(URLInputFile(stream)), выйдет ошибка, но как тогда отправить видео без скачивания?

@user27171043 так запиши в переменную поток: stream_url=stream.url и выводи уже ее

под stream ты подразумеваешь определенный поток, напримет по itag?

просто даже если так, то у меня выдает ошибку как раз в yt(url).streams, он не хочет продолжать с этого момента, а к примеру если вывести yt(url).title, то проблем никаких нет
